# With a DevExpress datagrid, what event is triggered by clicking Edit?

Tags: typescript, datagrid, devexpress

I can't find the answer to this in the documentation.

If I am using a DxDataGrid, and I click on a rows Edit button, what event is fired?

I have tried onRowValidating, onSelectionChanged, onEditing,                 onRowClick and onRowEditing (the one I thought most likely.)

It is none of these.

Comment: Thanks. OnEditingStart is the option I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation (v17.1)](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/):

> [`editingStart`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#editingStart)
>   *Fires before a row (in row edit mode) or a cell (in batch edit mode) switches into the editing state.*
>
> [`editorPreparing`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#editorPreparing)
>   *Fires before an editor is created.*
>
> [`editorPrepared`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#editorPrepared)
>   *Fires after an editor is created.*